# How to disable validation response from JAVA web service and .NET client?

Tags: java, .net, soap

I wat to call a soap web service (build in java) from client in .NET. To call this web service, I must use SSL connection and use X509 certificate. For now this step is OK. Now I have a problem when I try to call this web service, because there is a problem to validate the response. The error is:

> Unable to resolve KeyInfo for signature verification : KeyInfo ' SecurityKeyIdentifier \ r \ n ( \ r \ n IsReadOnly = False , \ r \ n Count = 1 , \ r \ n Clause [ 0 ] = X509IssuerSerialKeyIdentifierClause (Issuer = ' CN = testedoca , C = US ' , Serial = ' 1342448880 ' ) \ r \ n ) \ r \ n ' , token available ' SecurityTokenResolver \ r \ n ( \ r \ n TokenCount = 1 , \ r \ n TokenEntry [ 0 ] = ( AllowedReferenceStyle = External , Token = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken , Parameters = System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters : \ r \ nInclusionMode : Never \ r \ nReferenceStyle : Internal \ r \ nRequireDerivedKeys : False \ r \ nX509ReferenceStyle : Any )

I have read on web that there is a problem from JAVA and .NET

Now to fixed this problem, I want to disable validation response from .NET but I'm not able to do this.

How can I disable validation response???